# Run code in CSS file in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, css, iis, iis-7, server-side

In my CSS file I would like to have definitions such as:

```
.hr {
    background:url('<%=CommonFunctions.AllocateStaticPath("/images/hr.png") %>');
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 40px 0;
}
```

This would be useful to me, as the path to each image differs on the production server and the development server and the function correctly sets the resources path.  Being able to do this would simplify my publishing process.

How can I enable IIS7 to run ASP.net on CSS files?  I've tried renaming the CSS file to `.ashx` and creating a rewrite rule but this seems to always 404.

Comment: Take a look over [here](http://cfouquet.blogspot.fi/2006/06/making-dynamic-css-content-with-aspnet.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question inspired me to do some testing to see if I could somehow get the asked for syntax to work.

It turned out to be relatively easy. After a few different test versions, this is what I ended up doing.

## Configuration

1. Create a brand new web application to test in
2. Create a folder called `DynCss` where the css files that need dynamic processing will be put
3. Register `.css` files to be handled by the Page handler for requests to this folder. For this I added the following to `web.config`:

   ```
   <configuration>
      <system.web>
           ...
           <httpHandlers>
               <add type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" path="/DynCss/*.css" verb="GET"/>
           </httpHandlers>
           ...
       </system.web>
   </configuration>
   ```
4. Register a build handler for `.css` files:

   ```
   <configuration>
      <system.web>
           ...
           <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
               <buildProviders>
                   <add extension=".css" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
               </buildProviders>
           </compilation>
           ...
       </system.web>
   </configuration>
   ```

After doing these changes, I can proceed to testing it.

## Testing

For the purpose of testing I added `DynamicStyles.css` to the `DynCss` folder. Contents of `DynamicStyles.css`:

```
<%@ Page Title="DynamicStyles.css" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
          Response.ContentType="text/css";
          Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    }
</script>
body {
    font-weight: <%= TestDynamicCss.Code.Constants.FontWeight %>;
}
```

**Note**: The `TestDynamicCss.Code.Constants.FontWeight` referrs to a static property on a static class. I simply returns the string "bold".

Finally, I link to it in `Default.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestDynamicCss._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <link href="/DynCss/DynamicStyles.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET! Is this now bold? Why yes, it is!
    </h2>
</asp:Content>
```

## Comments

Using this approach you get the behaviour that you asked for. The drawbacks are that you don't get any automatic cache handling as you do for static css files. Also, this approach (as far as I can tell) makes it impossible to use the Css bundling features of Asp.Net 4.5. Also (needless to say) you don't get C# intellisense when *coding* in the Css file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background:url('<%= CommonFunctions.AllocateStaticPath("/images/hr.png") %>');
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo!  The problem is I need the CSS file to actually run that code.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create an ASPX page that returns CSS instead of HTML? Then reference the .aspx file in your CSS declaration.

Comment: I can do this and it works, but it feels a bit wrong linking to an aspx file as a css file.  Not sure if browsers would cache it differently etc.

Comment: Just use `Response.Cache.SetExpires` and manually control the cache. The browser doesn't care about the file extension, only the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use <del>the ashx handler</del> a page and add the response header:

```
Content-Type: text/css
```